# MetaPost pictures in PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, graphics, metapost

To include MetaPost pictures in a latex file compiled by pdflatex I usually do something like

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
...
\includegraphics{filename-without-mps}
```

but this requires all metapost output to have extension `.mps` (which is *usually* fine — one can just add the line `filenametemplate "%j-%c.mps";` into `.mp` source). Is there a way to include `mps` pictures with their usual filenames (`smth.1`, `smth.2`, etc.)?

*Update:* I usually need it to recompile some old files with PDFLaTeX — so I need some recipe that adds couple of lines in the preamble but not requires to changes *everything*.

---

I tried to invent some hack (for Windows, to be compiled with `pdflatex -enable-write18`):

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{pdf}{.1.pdf}{`copy #1 #1.eps && epstopdf #1.eps}
...
\includegraphics{smth.1}
```

which indeed generates `smth.1.pdf` but fails with the error

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `smth-1-converted-to.1.pdf' not found.
```

*Update 2:* The question was answered but maybe someone knows how to make this hack work?

Comment: @vanden it's not a question about metapost — are you sure it needs `metapost` tag?

Comment: I don't do much graphics. I took the presence of "metapost" in the title and the details about metapost extensions to indicate metapost content. But, as you as asker think not, I've reverted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{*}{} 
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.2}{mps}{*}{} 
% etc.
```

Comment: Now I'm feeling infinitely stupid

Comment: Even "\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}", maybe. But AFAIR it didn't work in some situation...

Answer (score 6):

Almost five years after the question.

With the latest versions of Metapost it is possible to change the default naming scheme for output files: the statement

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";
```

will produce, from file `name.mp`. files named as `name-1.mps` and so on. This is much preferable, because *no* further instruction is needed under `pdflatex`, which knows how to process MPS files.

Under LuaLaTeX, the `luamplib` package allows for direct embedding of Metapost code in the document.

The same is possible under all engines with the packages `gmp` or `mpgraphics`. The package `emp` also allows something similar, but with several limitations.

Comment: It should be said, however, that the embedding of MetaPost code by `mpgraphics` and `gmp` is necessarily less direct than the one allowed by `luamplib` with LuaLaTeX: you have to activate the `shell-escape` option with `gmp` as with `mpgraphics` if you want your pictures processed in one run. This is not the case with `luamplib`. This one having still the obvious disadvantage of being compatible with Lua(La)TeX only :-)

Comment: @fpast Everything you said is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Do you know that there's a package for encapsulating metapost figures in LaTeX? It's called [emp](http://ctan.org/pkg/emp).

Comment: Didn't know about it, thanks (but it certainly doesn't resolve my problem).

Comment: Just trying add helpful information. :)

Comment: Does emp have any support for Luatex/mplib?

Comment: LuaTeX is based on PDFTeX and has mplib baked in so there should be no need for encapsulation of MetaPost graphics.

Comment: @Charles, @Sharpie: in luatex, emp is superceded by the 'luamplib' package, which defines an environment and makes sure the library results are correctly included in the output.